# Convert custom object to dataframe

Tags: pandas, tuples, converters

I have this code that genrates a tuple object. I would like to convert that into a panda dataframe. Please help.

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

pw = win32com.client.Dispatch("pwrworld.SimulatorAuto")

infile = "M:/myfile.pwb"

pw.OpenCase(infile)
print ('Case open succecssfully')
objecttype='Gen'
FieldArray = ["BusNum", "GenID", "GenMW", "GenAGCAble"]

genout=pw.GetParametersMultipleElement(objecttype, FieldArray,[])
#______________________________________
#How can I put genout into a dataframe?
#______________________________________    
print (type(genout))
#This prints <class 'tuple'>
print (len(genout))
#This prints 2
```